# Concurrent Http Requests in LibGDX

Tags: java, http, concurrency, request, libgdx

I have a question.

I need to send concurrent Http Requests. 
As I understand, LibGdx doesn't allow that.

I checked the code in the Net module. There is an AsyncExecutor with max 1 concurrent jobs. So, no more than 1 task can be executed at a time, others will be queued. So, as I understand, I need to receive the response of the first request in order to send the 2nd. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else will need this, just let you know, that I'm right.

But it is changed in the 1.9.10 version, which will be released in a few days.